# append() or appendTo() for fontawesome

Tags: jquery, html, append, appendto

I have this scenario.

In title `<h2></h2>` I want to put fontawesome icon before text.
Ex.

```
  <h2 id="test"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> THIS IS TITLE</h2>
```

I will add manual icon for all title, but if any title stay empty (without icon), the script add default icon

```
  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
```

I have tried with this script but it is not working.

```
$("#test(:empty)").append('<h2><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></h2>');
```

Any suggestion to fix this problem?

Edit
 This one i need for all blocks in sidebar. Structure of block's is:

```
        <div class="sidebar">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-users"></i><a href="#"> Title 1</a></h2>
        <ul>
                        <li>

                            <div class="user"></div>
                        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And 2-nt sidebar same class different title

```
        <div class="sidebar">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-users"></i><a href="#"> Title 2</a></h2>
        <ul>
                        <li>

                            <div class="user"></div>
                        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And block 3-th is without icon

```
        <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>HERE ADDD DEFAULT ICON <a href="#"> Title 1</a></h2>
        <ul>
                        <li>

                            <div class="user"></div>
                        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I hope now is clear

Comment: So where's the text coming from? You probably want `prepend` instead, but it's not really clear what you're doing here, you're inserting both the icon and the H2, and there is no text present?

Comment: Note `$("#test")` will work for one `<h2>` only. Or do you have duplicate IDs?

Comment: @adeneo the text for title is different for all titles. And i want to add default icon in all h2 with id="test" who do not manually add an icon.

Comment: @ShaunakD i have test id for all title i want to add icon.

Comment: You can't have duplicate ID's, they should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS using [Pseudo-Classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp).

```
.sidebar h2:empty:before {font-family: 'FontAwesome';content: '\f100';}
.sidebar h2:before {font-family: 'FontAwesome';content: '\f0c0';}

<div class="sidebar">
    <h2>User Name</h2>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97r0y0c0/2/)

Comment: Hey @Geoffey please help me how to move title rignt. http://jsfiddle.net/kalco/KCXVM/14/

Answer (score 0):

You are appending an `h2` to an `h2`. Better yet, set your html to:

```
$("#test(:empty)").html('<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>');
```

Also, you should not give multiple elements the same `id`. For this, you should use a class and call like:

```
$(".test(:empty)").html('<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> My default title!');
```

Answer (score 0):

> in title `<h2></h2>` i want to put fontawesome icon before text

```
$("h2(:empty)").html(function(){
    return "<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>"+this.innerText;
});
```

---

Note `$('#test(:empty)')` will search for the first element with `#test`,and I guess you already have one `h2` non-empty.

You **[should not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)** have elements with same IDs, it must be unique in a document. Use `data-*` attributes - `data-id`

```
<h2 data-id="test">....

$("h2[data-id='test'](:empty)")
```

or class

```
<h2 class="test">....

$("h2.test(:empty)")
```